# How to align text or Image with numerical values in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I am new to **CSS** but do know **HTML**, I was creating a website as part of my ***learning process***. My problem is that I **can't align** text or images with **numerical values** such as -10px or -5%. All I can do is align it with text-align: left or float: left. Here's the part where I face the problem, I need to align *a logo next to my Logo name.* It's just like the StackOverflow logo next to the text (*ya, I noticed that it's an Image and no text*) Here's my header:

```
<body style="background-color: #111827;">
    <header>
        <img style="border: 3px solid #ddd;height: 65px;width: 65px; border-radius: 15%; float: left;" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50" alt="some-pic">
    <h1 style=" color: white; font-family:Agency FB; text-align: left; font-size: 50px;">Some Title</h1>
    </header>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

But this looks weird because there's no space between the logo and the text. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Hey, it's recommended to use an **external CSS file** instead of your actual inline styling, it's easier to understand, and better to do the maintenance. This is not going to solve your problem, but it's a good practice to separate the responsabilities while developing sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<h1 style=" color: white; font-family:Agency FB; text-align: left; font-size: 50px; margin-left:100px">Some Title</h1>
```

Just add margin-left attribute to the H1 tag it would suffice your requirement

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I did tried the margin attribute but didn't know there was a margin-left attribute

Answer (score 0):

Move the *whole*  `img` tag *into*  the `h1` tag (at its start)